# Jenkins - Publish Over SSH Plugin: How to copy directory

Tags: jenkins, ssh, build, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to use [Jenkins' Publish Over SSH](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin#PublishOverSSHPlugin-Configure) plugin to copy all files AND sub-directories of some given directory, but so far, I've only able to copy files and NOT directory.

I have a directory named `foo` in my workspace, and during the build, I want to copy everything in this directory to a remote server.
I've tried this pattern `foo/**`, but it doesn't copy all sub-directories.

Any suggestion? Or this is not the plugin I should be using?

Thanks

Comment: `foo/**` in "Source files" does create all subdirectories and copy files respectiely for me.

Answer (score 8):

For recursive copy of directory you should give

> foo/**/*

I verified this on my laptop using locally deploying Jenkins. It works fine.

Comment: If you want to send the whole workspace like it happened to me, just use **/* in the Source files input text.